# In C, how do I append to a file line but not the end of the file?

Tags: c, io, printf

I have usernames and tweets stored in a file the following format:

username1:message1:message2:...:messageN

username2:message1:message2:...:messageN

...

usernameN:message1:message2:...:messageN

In the case where the file has a line where the username == the username with a new message attached, I want to append :newMessage to a line as formatted above.

How do I do this with C (with cygwin if that matters)?  Here's the code block I wrote that I'm having trouble with.

```
         while(fgets(line, MAXBUFF, fp) != NULL){  // get each line of file
             if (strncmp(line, tweetUsr, strlen(tweetUsr)) == 0){
                 usrFound = 1;
                 fprintf(filePointer, ":");
                 fprintf(filePointer, tweet);
                 break;
             }

             memset(&line[0], 0, sizeof(line));  //reset line array
         }
```

What I expect to happen is for the message to be appended to the end of the line since filePointer should be pointing to the end of the current line, but what's actually happening is the message is being appended to the end of the file.

I tried this using r+ mode in fopen.  what do I have to do in order to be able to append to the current line rather than the end of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative to Jonathon Reinhart's answer would be:

- read from the actual file line by line
- write to a temp file while adding new message of certain users
- when done (successfully done) delete original file and rename/move the temp file to the original.

This approach will bring more performance (in the worst case where each user has a new message) if you are adding messages of multiple users at a time.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the most sense with my implementation

Answer (score 9):

You can't *insert* data in the middle of a file. If you try to write, you'll be writing over data that's already there.

If you want to do this, you need to:

- `fseek` to the position you want to write to
- `fread` from that point to the end of the file into a buffer
- `fwrite` what you want to inserted
- `fwrite` the buffer you read out

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a structure that is more flexible than a sequential file. Use some form of database, and append the messages to the list of messages for the user.